# from jquery mobile 1.3.2 to 1.4.3, checkbox horizontal failed

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-checkbox

Here's the html:

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="buddies" />
</form>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var usr = json[i];
    var mid = usr.mid;
    var input = '<input id="' + mid + '" type="checkbox"';
    var photo = usr.photo;
    if (typeof photo === 'undefined') {
    photo = '<span class="middle"></span><br/>';
    no_photo_ids[no_photo_ids.length] = mid;
    } else {
    photo = '<span class="middle"><img src="' + photo + '"/></span><br/>';
    if (max_invite_messages-- > 0) {
        input += ' checked="checked"';
    }
    }
    input += '>';
    var label = '<label for="' + mid + '">' + photo + usr.name + '</label>';
    $('#buddies').append(input);
    $('#buddies').append(label);
}
$('#buddies').trigger('create');
```

It works all right in jquery mobile 1.3.2, just like:
[image]

But it messed up in 1.4.3, just like:
[image]

Comment: It seems like it is something else in your code that changed bc the documentation does not suggest that this setup has deprecated. It looks like your var input is missing a ">" at the end though.  This might be creating an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control group loses control after dynamic add of radio button - jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059478/control-group-loses-control-after-dynamic-add-of-radio-button-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: [Control group loses control after dynamic add of radio button - jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059478/control-group-loses-control-after-dynamic-add-of-radio-button-jquery-mobile)

1.3.2 is easy to work like this:

```
$('#buddies').append(...);
$('#buddies').append(...);
...
$('#buddies').trigger('create');
```

1.4.3 is much a mess like this:

```
$('#buddies').controlgroup("container").append(...);
$('#buddies').controlgroup("container").append(...);
...
$('#buddies').enhanceWithin().controlgroup("refresh");
```

Now it works pretty good:

[image]